# Kotlin: Why are unary plus/minus not able to infer generic type from assignment?

Tags: generics, kotlin

Why are unary plus/minus not able to infer generic type from assignment?

Using `invoke`, for example: `inline operator fun <reified T> invoke(): T`

You can call the method and are able to use it... for example `val foo: Long = this()`

But, using `unaryPlus` or `unaryMinus` in the same fashion doesn't work.

The method signature: `inline operator fun <reified T> unaryPlus(): T`

The non-working call: `val foo: Long = +this`

[image]

Comment: Your example appears incomplete, you don't show if this inline operator is declared inside of a class or not.  It cannot be top level because it must be a class method, or extension on a class.  So please provide enclosing class.

Comment: @JaysonMinard It is declared within a class like so: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10453

Answer (score 3):

Operator must be declared as extension function or member of some class:

```
inline operator fun <reified T> T.unaryPlus(): T = this
```

Then you can use it on any **T**:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    data class Type(val value: Int)
    val foo = +Type(42)
}
```

Comment: This is not related to the problem. My problem is clearly a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10453